# cygwin + tmux on windows 7 - why won't tmux use the current path?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, tmux

I have used tmux on linux systems and Mac OSX with no problem. I am aware that as of version 1.9 (I have 1.9a according to `tmux -V`), you are required to do something along the lines of `tmux split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"`. That doesn't work, though. Nothing seems to work.

The best "hint" I can give is that the `-c` parameter appears to be recognized in some form, as I get an error about an invalid path if I give it an explicit path that I know does not exist. However, giving it an explicit path does nothing (I thought maybe there was a problem with using `pane_current_path`.

There is a chance there are two questions here, as tmux does not start in the current folder, which is default behavior, I believe.

Anybody know what's going on? Is this expected behavior? Am I missing a library somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote is about... My only assumption (since there is no direct feedback) is that it is from someone who is not familiar with cygwin and/or tmux, so I'm not sure why there were here to begin with.If maintaining the current path works out of the box for others, that sure would be nice to know.

Comment: Just installed tmux on cygwin, seeing this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @nfarrar - kraiz answered with the solution, which the OP failed to acknowledge and accept.

Answer (score 25):

With the following in your `.tmux.conf`::

```
set-environment -g CHERE_INVOKING 1
```

Then `tmux split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"` drop me at`/`, but `tmux split-window -c $PWD` works.

Found at http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/5921

Comment: This does not work for me. When running the command `tmux show-environment`, should CHERE_INVOKING appear?

Comment: This `CHERE_INVOKING` saved my working life. Am using `tmux 2.6` in cygwin and this finally is the beginning of a new day for me. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks. Solved my issue of tmux 2.6 in cygwin.

Comment: Words cant express the joy this answer has given me, to think I suffered this long with the same issue. 1000 thanks!

Answer (score 16):

[kraiz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26840429/513397) using `set-environment` and `$PWD` did not work for me.

Instead, I set the environment variable in my login script (`~/.bash_profile` for bash, `~/.zprofile` for zsh):

```
export CHERE_INVOKING=1
```

Also, `$PWD` did not work for me, but `#{pane_current_path}` did. Here's a snippet of my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Software: tmux 2.0, Cygwin 1.7.35, zsh 5.0.6, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

That solution instead of CHERE_INVOKING used above will preserve your symlink path:

```
# .bashrc
# set pwd for tmux
function set_tmux_pwd() {
    [ -n "$TMUX" ] && tmux setenv TMUXPWD_$(tmux display -p "#D" | tr -d %) "$PWD"
    return 0
}
function my_cd() {
    \cd $1
    set_tmux_pwd
}
set_tmux_pwd
alias cd=my_cd
```

and

```
# .tmux.conf
# this support symbolic link
bind c run-shell 'tmux new-window "cd \"$(tmux show-environment $(echo "TMUXPWD_#D" | tr -d %) | sed -e "s/^.*=//")\"; exec $SHELL"'
bind '"' run-shell 'tmux split-window -v "cd \"$(tmux show-environment $(echo "TMUXPWD_#D" | tr -d %) | sed -e "s/^.*=//")\"; exec $SHELL"'
bind '%' run-shell 'tmux split-window -h "cd \"$(tmux show-environment $(echo "TMUXPWD_#D" | tr -d %) | sed -e "s/^.*=//")\"; exec $SHELL"'
```

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1282#issuecomment-559033047

It works on cygwin 3.1.4 and tmux 2.6

Answer (score 0):

`#{pane_current_path}` always left me at `/`. `"$PWD"` always left me at `~`. I uninstalled the ubuntu package and compiled from the [github master branch](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/tree/master) and now it works perfectly with `#{pane_current_path}`.

Comment: Did you change anything else? It didn't work for me (checked with master).

Comment: Nope all I had to do was install from master. Did you install all the dependancies?

Comment: Yes. `tmux -V` says 2.4.